# default route per a specific page angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-router

i am using angular 5 and i wont to add a default rote, but per a specific page.

for example, i have this route for "log-in" page:

```
  { path: 'log-in', component: LogInComponent }
```

and i wont that if user will try to go to not exits url like this:

```
log-in/3/4 
log-in/3/4/5
log-in/3/4/5/6
```

i redirect him to "not-found-page**1**".

but if the user will try to go to not exits url that not related to "log-in" page. like this:

```
registration/3/4
home/3/4
```

i redirect him to "not-found-page**2**"

obviously i can't use:

```
{ path: '**' }
```

because it will work for all pages as one.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{ path: '**' }`. But you have to look, that the routes are defined in the right order.

You could define a `componentless` route with `child routes` with empty path like this:

```
{ path: 'log-in', children: [
  {path : '' , component: LogInComponent }
  {path : '**' , component: notFoundPage1 }
]},
... other routes
{ path : '**' , component: notFoundPage2 }
```

This way `/log-in` would be directed to `LogInComponent` because empty child routes will be routed there, if nothing is after `/log-in`. All other routes with `log-in/*` would be routed to the `notFoundPage1` because the second path is matching.

All routes that are not related to `/log-in` will be routed to `notFoundPage2`

**NOTE:** The order in this configuration is important. You can even define other child routes if you want. But the `path: '**'` must be at the end so it can catch all undefined child routes.

Comment: awesome solution :)

Comment: Glad i could help you. If it works for your use-case, you could accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use your configuration like this

```
{ path: 'log-in', component: LogInComponent }
{ path: 'log-in/:id/:anotherID', component: notFoundPage1 }
{ path: 'unKnownRoute', component: notFoundPage2 }
```

PS: This is valid only if you have some specific set of condition

Comment: unfortunately, i have not. it's can bee with no limit params.

Comment: okay , so can you please explain bit more about your use case in your question to be more clear

Comment: i add more example in the question. thank you anyway!